# Pyspark- how to check one data frame column contains string from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For the two dataframes below, I'm trying to see if `name1` in `df1` contains `name2` in `df2`. How to achieve this? I'm thinking of doing a join but there's no join key. Can I specify something like `if name2 contains name1 then join them`, and result in the output below? Many thanks for your help

```
df1:
Name1   Colour 
Lisa    ('blue','yellow')
Bart       ('pink', 'yellow')
Homer     ('green', 'black')
Maggie      ('yellow','orange','blue')

df2
Name2          Age 
Lisa S.        5
Bart Simpsons  8
Bob            10
Ben            30

expected output:
Name2          Age    Name1   colour
Lisa S.        5      Lisa    ('blue','yellow')
Bart Simpsons  8.     Bart       ('pink', 'yellow')
```

Comment: Split the Name2  column and create another one with the name and then join

Comment: can df2 have two names with same first name, e.g., `Bart Simpson` and `Bart Summers`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
As @samkart mentioned, we can use direct `.crossJoin()`. Updated the solution with that.

---

As there is no common key to join, you may have to perform cross join and compare each value against the rest. This can be done by introducing a "dummy_key". Then just filter the rows by string `contains()`:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([["Lisa","('blue','yellow')"], ["Bart","('pink', 'yellow')"], ["Homer","('green', 'black')"], ["Maggie","('yellow','orange','blue')"]], ["Name1","Colour"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([["Lisa S.",5], ["Bart Simpsons",8], ["Bob",10], ["Ben",30]], ["Name2","Age"])

result_df = df2.crossJoin(df1)
result_df = result_df.filter(F.col("Name2").contains(F.col("Name1")))

[Out]:
+-------------+---+-----+------------------+
|        Name2|Age|Name1|            Colour|
+-------------+---+-----+------------------+
|      Lisa S.|  5| Lisa| ('blue','yellow')|
|Bart Simpsons|  8| Bart|('pink', 'yellow')|
+-------------+---+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: see [`crossJoin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-crossjoin) method.

Comment: Thank you @samkart. Updated the source code. I originally answered this question thinking it uses pandas. Then converted it to spark :)